# HTTP 403 Forbidden SharePoint 2010 CA - only in IE but not FireFox

Tags: http, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, http-headers, fiddler

When I tried to access SharePoint CA from the client after the installation I got this error
"HTTP 403 Forbidden" only when I use IE.
I tried everything but when I change the browser to Firefox I get the windows authentication popup.

I thought it's a firewall problem or I did something wrong when I install SharePoint but I think it had something to do with IE and the request header.

Any idea?

```
GET http://srv002:9999/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/jpeg, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-application, application/xaml+xml, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: srv002:9999


HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid: 9cfc2a00-39ef-41f6-b89f-d63239b4afb3
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.7106
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Tue, 04 Feb 2014 07:08:54 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication



------------------------------------------------------------------

GET http://srv002:9999/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/jpeg, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-application, application/xaml+xml, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: srv002:9999
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4IIogAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAbEdAAAADw==


HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid: 40ae372c-acba-4800-b684-1a4751169fc3
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAABgAGADgAAAAFgomicjttOyWACKEAAAAAAAAAAIAAgAA+AAAABgGxHQAAAA9TAE0ARgACAAYAUwBNAEYAAQAMAFMAUgBWADAAMAAyAAQAFABzAG0AZgAuAGcAbwB2AC4AcwBhAAMAIgBTAHIAdgAwADAAMgAuAHMAbQBmAC4AZwBvAHYALgBzAGEABQAUAHMAbQBmAC4AZwBvAHYALgBzAGEABwAIAG0GvfZ3Ic8BAAAAAA==
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.7106
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Tue, 04 Feb 2014 07:08:54 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication



------------------------------------------------------------------

GET http://srv002:9999/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/jpeg, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-application, application/xaml+xml, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: NTLM 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
Host: srv002:9999


HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://srv002:9999/_layouts/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Fsrv002%3A9999
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid: 69b66e7a-3211-4023-8abb-3dc9847c6e86
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.7106
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Tue, 04 Feb 2014 07:08:54 GMT
Content-Length: 196



------------------------------------------------------------------

GET http://srv002:9999/_layouts/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Fsrv002%3A9999 HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/jpeg, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-application, application/xaml+xml, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4IIogAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAbEdAAAADw==
Host: srv002:9999


HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid: b66fc0f0-0a2c-4172-81a8-1c9e372ca6ba
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAABgAGADgAAAAFgomiurTeqPQpMIgAAAAAAAAAAIAAgAA+AAAABgGxHQAAAA9TAE0ARgACAAYAUwBNAEYAAQAMAFMAUgBWADAAMAAyAAQAFABzAG0AZgAuAGcAbwB2AC4AcwBhAAMAIgBTAHIAdgAwADAAMgAuAHMAbQBmAC4AZwBvAHYALgBzAGEABQAUAHMAbQBmAC4AZwBvAHYALgBzAGEABwAIABfJwfZ3Ic8BAAAAAA==
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.7106
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Tue, 04 Feb 2014 07:08:54 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication



------------------------------------------------------------------

GET http://srv002:9999/_layouts/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Fsrv002%3A9999 HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/jpeg, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-application, application/xaml+xml, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: NTLM 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
Host: srv002:9999


HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid: ac436a2d-eadc-4a98-a382-be0432840d60
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=yxptiwufledck2452zqacr2f; path=/; HttpOnly
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.7106
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Tue, 04 Feb 2014 07:08:54 GMT



------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP/403 suggests that Internet Explorer automatically responded to an earlier HTTP/401 demand for credentials by automatically submitting the current user's login credentials, which the server decided were not valid for the target resource. Hence it returned the HTTP/403 Access Denied.

Firefox, in contrast, does not respond to a HTTP/401 challenge by automatically submitting the Windows users' credentials, and therefore the Credential Dialog is shown.

*If* you submit exactly the same credentials using Firefox's credentials dialog, then you *should* get the same HTTP/403 response at that point.

Comment: Can we make IE behave like Firefox if we change some policies in the DC or some settings in SharePoint or maybe IIS?

Comment: IE sends credentials automatically in the Intranet zone; see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/07/06/integrated-windows-authentication-kerberos-ntlm-http-400-error-for-16kb-authorization-header.aspx and  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/06/05/the-local-intranet-security-zone.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution..
I had to remove the SharePoint Central Administration URL in IE Security settings from Local Intranet and put it in Trusted site so I can edit Custom level > User Authentication > logon > Prompt for username and password.